# Firebase 'auth/invalid-action-code' on auth.confirmPasswordReset()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, reset-password

I am trying to reset password using `auth.confirmPasswordReset()`. My oobcode is valid, but I still get the `auth/invalid-action-code` error. (I'm using react Js)

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const oobCode = urlParams.get('oobCode')
    if (oobCode) {
        auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(oobCode).then(email => {
            console.log('valid oobCode')
            this.setState({ email, oobCode })
        }).catch(err => {
            this.setState({ expired: true })
        })
    }
}
onChangeNewPassword = (e) => {
    this.setState({ newPassword: e.target.value })
}
onSubmit = () => {
    auth.confirmPasswordReset(this.state.oobcode, this.state.newPassword).then(res => {
        this.setState({ errorText: "", passwordChanged: true })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err)
        this.setState({ errorText: err.message })
    });
}
render(){
   return (
        <input 
          placeholder='New Password' 
          type='password' 
          value={this.state.newPassword} 
          onChange={this.onChangeNewPassword}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Continue</button>
   )
}
```

On console I get this:

```
valid oobCode
err t {code: 'auth/invalid-action-code', message: 'The action code is invalid. This can happen if the… is malformed, expired, or has already been used.', a: null}
```

Comment: Hey did you ever get this sorted out? Im having a similar experience and have no idea why its happening

Comment: Yes, it was a spelling mistake. At some places I had written 'oobcode' and at other places 'oobCode'